# NSDateFormatter always return 2010-12-31 23:00:00 +0000

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using this code to format a date from a string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy"];

NSDate *dateStart = [dateFormat dateFromString:[thisEvent dateEvent]];
```

`[thisEvent dateEvent]` contains this date: `Saturday,  09 April 2011`

I don't know why `dateStart` contains `2010-12-31 23:00:00 +0000`

where I'm wrong?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you wish to print the date it will be o.k -

```
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy"];

    NSDate *dateStart = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"Saturday, 09 April 2011"];

    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateStart];
    NSLog(@"%@",formattedDateString);//returns "Saturday, 09 April 2011"//
```

hope it helps

shani

Comment: ok, it seems that on the simulator it works, but when I use dateFromString on the iPhone the object dateStart is always set to 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: ok solved! i had to set NSLocale

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
Thank You